# C# Lists: How to copy elements from one list to another, but only certain properties

Tags: c#, list

So I have a list of objects with a number of properties. Among these properties are **name** and **id**. Let's call this object ExtendedObject. I've also declared a new List of *different* objects that have *only* the properties **name** and **id**. Let's call this object BasicObject.

What I'd like to do is convert or copy (for lack of better words) the List of ExtendedObject objects to a list of BasicObject objects. I know C# Lists have a lot of interesting methods that can be useful, so I wondered if there were an easy way to say something to the effect of:

```
basicObjectList = extendedObjectList.SomeListMethod<BasicObject>(some condition here);
```

But I realize it may end up looking nothing like that. I also realize that I could just loop through the list of ExtendedObjects, create a new BasicObject from each ExtendedObject's name and id, and push it onto a list of BasicObjects. But I was hoping for something a little more elegant than that.

Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It depends on exactly how you'd construct your `BasicObject` from an `ExtendedObject`, but you could probably use the [`ConvertAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73fe8cwf.aspx) method:

```
List<BasicObject> basicObjectList =
    extendedObjectList.ConvertAll(x => new BasicObject
                                           {
                                               id = x.id,
                                               name = x.name
                                           });
```

Or, if you prefer, you could use the LINQ [`Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select.aspx) method and then [convert back to a list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx):

```
List<BasicObject> basicObjectList =
    extendedObjectList.Select(x => new BasicObject
                                       {
                                           id = x.id,
                                           name = x.name
                                       }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 8):

if you are on .NET 3.5 or greater this could be done by using LINQ projections:

```
basicObjectList = extendedObjectList.Select(x => new BasicObject { Id=x.Id, Name=x.Name})
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var basicObjectList = extendedObjectList.Select(eo => new BasicObject { name = eo.name, id = eo.id });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the OP's suggestion of "BasicObject" was just a pseudonym for a resulting object with a specific subset of properties from the original set.  Anonymous types are your friend (as indicated by @mumtaz).

Assuming the following *extendedObjectList* if of IEnumerable<T> (including a List):

```
// "var" used so that runtime infers the type automatically
var subset = extendedObjectList
   // you can use any Linq based clause for filtering
   .Where(a => <conditions>)
   // where the runtime creates a runtime anonymous type to describe your "BasicObject"
   .Select(a => new { a.Property1, a.Property2, a.Property3 })
   // conversion to a List collection of your anonymous type
   .ToList();
```

At this point, *subset* contains a List of an anonymous (runtime) type that contains three properties - *Property1*, *Property2*, *Property3*.

You can manipulate this resulting list as follows:

```
// execute an anonymous delegate (method) for each of the new anonymous objects
subset.ForEach
(
   basicObject =>
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Property1 - {0}", basicObject.Property1);
      Console.WriteLine("Property2 - {0}", basicObject.Property2);
      Console.WriteLine("Property3 - {0}", basicObject.Property3);
   }
);

// grab the first object off the list
var firstBasicObject = subset.First();

// sort the anonymously typed list
var sortedSubset = subset.OrderBy(a => a.Property1).ToList();
```

Once the runtime has resolved the new object (of any combination of properties from the source object), you can use it virtually any way that you wish.

For Linq-to-Sql applications (using IQueryable<T>), the *Select* statement can be used to obtain specific column data (instead of the entire row), thereby creating an anonymous type to describe a subset of column data for a given row.